# Do not include fragment in backstack using Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I'm working on an app where users can create events.  I would like to make it so that the after they create the event the back button would not take them to the creation flow, but to the screen before the creation flow.  Something like:

Main Screen -> Creation Flow -> Event Summary

Then if they press the back button I want it to go

Event Summary (back button) Main Screen

I've gotten close with:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/createMeetFragment"
    android:name=".CreateMeetFragment"
    android:label="CreateMeetFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_createMeetFragment_to_meet_detail_graph"
        app:destination="@id/meet_detail_graph"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/mainFragment" />
</fragment>
```

This works well enough in that it will pop-up to the Main screen.  I haven't found much documentation for these pop behavior options just [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptions.Builder).

The issue I have with this solution is that as I understand it, it will pop until we get to the MainScreen, regardless of how the user got to the event creation.  I'd prefer a solution that just pops to the screen before the creation flow, allowing for multiple entry points to the creation flow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'd prefer a solution that just pops to the screen before the creation
>   flow, allowing for multiple entry points to the creation flow.

You should not pop up to the main screen but to **the first screen of creation flow inclusively**.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/createMeetFragment"
    android:name=".CreateMeetFragment"
    android:label="CreateMeetFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_createMeetFragment_to_meet_detail_graph"
        app:destination="@id/meet_detail_graph"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/firstCreateFlowFragment" 
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</fragment>
```

Comment: I appreciate the thought and I think this could make sense, but the main thing I'm trying to understand is if it is possible to pop to the screen that brought me to the first create screen when there are multiple options.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, if you pop up to the first create screen inclusively (i.e. this screen is destroyed as well), then you are at the screen that brought you there. Isn't it?

Comment: You are 100% right, I had misread this as you suggesting I should navigate to the first screen.  I get it now, tested and it works.  Accepting!

Comment: I tried this solution its worked for me but I have to remove 
 app:popUpToInclusive="true"